# Generic class that extends collection generic class

Tags: java, generics

I'm using [Guava's `LineProcessor`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LineProcessor.html) interface when reading lines from files. I've created my class called `Line Loader` which will store lines read. I want it to be generic on choice of collection lines should be stored in so I wrote something like this:

```
public abstract class LineLoader<T> implements LineProcessor<Collection<T>> {        
    private final Collection<T> result;

    public LineLoader() {
        this.result = init();
    }

    protected boolean add(final T line) {
        return result.add(line);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processLine(final String line) throws Exception {
        final T data = parser.parseLine(line);

        if (data == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return add(data);            
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract Collection<T> init();
}
```

where with `init()` method I force subclasses to chose type of collection, for example:

```
public abstract class LinkedLineLoader<T> extends LineLoader<T> {
    @Override
    protected Collection<T> init() {
        return new LinkedList<T>();
    }
}
```

I planned on doing this:

```
public class LineLoader<T> implements LineProcessor<C<T> extends Collection<T>> {        
    private final C<T> result;

    public LineLoader() {
        result = new C<T>();  
    }

    protected boolean add(final T line) {
        return result.add(line);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processLine(final String line) throws Exception {
        final T data = parser.parseLine(line);

        if (data == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return add(data);            
    }

    @Override
    public C<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

so that latter subclases (if needed) could do:

```
public class LinkedLineLoader<T> extends LineLoader<LinkedList<T>> {

}
```

but it's not possible. Is there a clean solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java it is not possible to create instances from generic type arguments, because generics are erased at run-time. Also, generic type arguments can not themselves declare additional type arguments like `C<T>`. Therefore the code you posted is entirely illegal and will not compile:

```
private final C<T> result; // illegal
result = new C<T>(); // illegal
```

Aside from that, your declaration of the type arguments itself has some flaws. The following code is no legal Java code:

```
public class LineLoader<T> implements LineProcessor<C<T> extends Collection<T>>
```

It should actually look e.g. like this:

```
public class LineLoader<T, C extends Collection<T>> implements LineProcessor<C>
```

As a solution to your problem, you could declare your `LineLoader` as shown above, and add a protected constructor, that takes the generic collection as an argument:

```
public abstract class LineLoader<T, C extends Collection<T>> implements LineProcessor<C> {        
    private final C result;

    protected LineLoader(C collection) {
        result = collection;  
    }

    protected boolean add(final T line) {
        return result.add(line);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processLine(final String line) throws IOException {
        final T data = parser.parseLine(line);

        if (data == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return add(data);            
    }

    @Override
    public C getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can implement your `LinkedLineLoader` like so:

```
class LinkedLineLoader<T> extends LineLoader<T, LinkedList<T>> {
    public LinkedLineLoader() {
        super(new LinkedList<>());
    }
}
```